# connection to mongoDB

Tags: node.js, mongodb

I am a new in nodeJS and mongodb. I can not connect my code with mongodb. here is my code. when I run this code it gives me this,

> (node:9160) DeprecationWarning: current URL string parser is
>   deprecated, and will be removed in a future version. To use the new
>   parser, pass option `{ useNewUrlParser: true }` to `MongoClient.connect`.

How can I fix it?

```
var express = require("express");
    var mongoose = require("mongoose");
    var passport = require("passport");
    var bodyParser = require("body-parser");
    var LocalStrategy = require("passport-local");
    var passportLocalMongoose = require("passport-local-mongoose");

    mongoose.connect("mongodb://localhost/mydb");

    // mongoose.connect("mongodb://localhost:27017/mydb_login", { useNewUrlParser: true })
    var app = express();

    app.set("view engine", "ejs");
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Connect mongo db to remote server nodejs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25790700/connect-mongo-db-to-remote-server-nodejs)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try it, I think it will help you.

```
let MONGOOSE = require('mongoose');    
MONGOOSE.connect('mongodb://127.0.0.1:27017/demo', (err, response)=>{
                if(err)
                    reject(err);
                else
                    resolve(null);
            });
```

Comment: in which file should I add this snippet?

Comment: You can create a new file or you can add it directly to server.js file. It totally depends on your structure.

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend to replace this statement of yours

```
mongoose.connect("mongodb://localhost/mydb");
```

with a one of this type:

```
mongoose.connect(uri)
.then(
    () => { 
      console.log("Connected");
    },
    err => {
      console.log(err); 
    }
);
```

This will help you to know wether the connection has been established or not and also if it is not established what is the corresponding error for the same.

Answer (score 0):

just add {useNewUrlParser: true} to the connection options object

> mongoose.connect("mongodb://localhost/mydb", { useNewUrlParser: true });

this is due to a new parser version

Answer (score 0):

Put this code inside your layout file, not in app.js:

```
var mongoose = require('mongoose');
mongoose.connect('mongodb://localhost:27017/yourDatabase', { useNewUrlParser: true });
var Schema = mongoose.Schema;
```

Then you can create your Schema layout, for example:

```
var mySchema = new Schema({
    first_name: String, 
    last_name: String
});
```

Answer (score 0):

### 100% Work Method just Follow Me

1. find The **mongoose.connect(db)** file in your project....
   its could be found in **Custom folder** or **server.js**
2. In **mongoose.connect(db)** replace **mongoose.connect(db,{ useNewUrlParser: true })**
3. See image    [image]